# Linq - group by a name, but still get the id

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

I'm trying to find duplicates in linq by a particular column (the name column), but I also wish to return the unique id, as I wish to bind to the ID to display additional information about the row.

I've dug around on stackoverflow, but can only find ways of finding duplicates in the fashion off:

- By the whole object
- By a particular property
- Getting the number of duplicates

The closest thing I could find was by specifying "Key" in my group by, but I'm ensure if that is working.

Ideally I'm hoping to output something that has the ID, Number of Duplicates.

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Please show sample input and expected output.

Comment: True @DanielHilgarth I was finding difficult to express what I was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have people collection:

```
from p in people
group p by p.Name into g
select new {
   Name = g.Key,
   NumberOfDuplicates = g.Count(),
   IDs = g.Select(x => x.ID)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the bit that I was missing was that I forgot / didn't realise that I could select from g.

Comment: In case it comes in useful to anyone: By adding an additional "from id in g.Select(s => s.ID)" it enabled me to flattern the results into 2 columns count / id.